# Close menu when clicking the screen or another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have two vertical menus and two buttons. Each menu only opens and closes if you click its button.

But I would like that by clicking on the "`showLeft`" button the "`showRight`" menu will be hidden.

And if I click anywhere on the monitor the two menus close

```
<button id="showLeft">Show/Hide Left Slide Menu</button>
<button id="showRight">Show/Hide Right Slide Menu</button>

<script>
    var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        body = document.body;

    showLeft.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
        disableOther( 'showLeft' );

    };
    showRight.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
        disableOther( 'showRight' );
    };


    function disableOther( button ) {
        if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
            classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
        }
        if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
            classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
        }
    }           

    var topNavBar = 50;
    var footer = 48;
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.cbp-spmenu').css('height', (height - (topNavBar+footer)));

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        $('.cbp-spmenu').css('height', (height - (topNavBar+footer)));
    });


</script>
```

Comment: What is `classie` ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Classie is being used here – class helper functions of Codrops

Comment: It's hard to help here, you should provide a live example

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki [Article that I'm following with the code](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/) and [the example of working menus](https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/) I'm only using the first two buttons so the javascript got smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1245/)**.

You need to remove the class `cbp-spmenu-open` of the other menu when you click like :

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
  classie.toggle(this, 'active');
  classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
  classie.remove(menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
};

showRight.onclick = function() {
  classie.toggle(this, 'active');
  classie.toggle(menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
  classie.remove(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
};
```

Comment: @Gislef is this what you was looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly, and how is it possible to click anywhere on the screen and hide the menus if one of them is open?

Comment: Another thing I'm testing and not working: when loading the page already open the left menu, I tried to use `window.onload`. code:  `window.onload = function(){
    classie.toggle(this, 'active');
       classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
   };`

Comment: Thank you again, why are the colors of the clicked buttons not being selected correctly?

Comment: Welcome anytime bro.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no object named `showLeft` or `showRight`, did you meant `menuLeft.onclick` and `menuRight.onclick` instead of `showLeft.onclick` and `showRight.onclick` respectively ?

Comment: Looking at the article you shared, it seems you need to define variables `showLeft` or `showRight` in your code.